# Highcharts overriding X or Y axis key for series data objects

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the examples in the highchart docs I see you can define your data like so:

```
[{ x: 100, y: 3}, { x: 105, y: 4} ...]
```

But I have non standard keys like this:

```
[{ myCustomXKey: 100, myCustomYKey: 3}, { myCustomXKey: 105, myCustomYKey: 4} ...]
```

Surely there must be a way to use my custom keys rather than the standard "x" and "y", right?  Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens if for a test, you substitute x and y for your custom keys?  It's been a while since I've used highcharts, but I remember keys being flexible with naming... But I also remember (just an FYI) I had many issues due to my JSON formatting being ever so slightly off - especially when trying to form JSON data for situations that strayed far from the examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My example above just has 2 keys but I'll actually have several unused keys in my data.  I could reformat the data to just be an array of arrays but I figured there must be a way to configure each axis to say:  xAxis: {key: "myCustomXKey"}

Comment: @trumb1mj did you get a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can update the data series like this

```js
var dataServer = [{
  myCustomXKey: 100,
  myCustomYKey: 3,
  myCustomZKey: 4
}, {
  myCustomXKey: 105,
  myCustomYKey: 4,
  myCustomZKey: 5
}, {
  myCustomXKey: 110,
  myCustomYKey: 5,
  myCustomZKey: 6
}, {
  myCustomXKey: 120,
  myCustomYKey: 6,
  myCustomZKey: 7
}]

function initialize(dataServer) {

  //suppose you need x,y,z data 
  var dataH = [];//creating array for chart
  for (var i = 0; i < dataServer.length; i++) {
    /*pushing objects into array*/
    dataH.push({
      x: dataServer[i].myCustomXKey,
      y: dataServer[i].myCustomYKey,
      z: dataServer[i].myCustomZKey
    })
  }

  Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
      type: 'bubble',
      plotBorderWidth: 1,
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'update chart data from server data'
    },

    series: [{
      data: dataH //add the variable here
    }]

  });
}
initialize(dataServer)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: any one giving -1, please add comments , so that I can help at most. Explanation above works and convert data format as required by highcharts.